# NoMethodError with deeply nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure if I'm structuring my application corretly (I've been learning Rails for 2 months now) but I am building a pretty deeply nested application that looks like this:

**user has_many accounts > accounts has_many characters > characters has_many items**

So it's 4 levels deep (that's the plan at least).

I'm currently at characters and I'm having trouble creating the form which is throwing up this error: `undefined method 'characters' for nil:NilClass` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKVxq.png)).

Here's the project on github: https://github.com/imjp/d2shed

**characters_controller.rb**

```
 class CharactersController < ApplicationController 
   def create
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
     @character = @account.characters.create(params[:character])
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end
```

**character.rb**

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :type  
  belongs_to :account
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@account, @account.characters.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.radio_button(:type, "SC") %>
    <%= f.label(:type, "SC") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:type, "HC") %>
    <%= f.label(:type, "HC") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:type, "SCL") %>
    <%= f.label(:type, "SCL") %>

    <%= f.radio_button(:type, "HCL") %>
    <%= f.label(:type, "HCL") %>
</div> 
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you don't define @account in the users controller in the show action,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
...
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @account = @user.accounts.first # Otherwise @account == nil
    ...
  end
...
end
```

Also, the route in your form don't look right.

The create action for the Character resource is like this in the routes:

```
POST /:user_id/accounts/:account_id/characters
```

So you need to provide, :user_id, :account_id, and character

like this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @account, @account.characters.build] %>
```

Comment: Hey man. I added the changes but I'm still getting a `undefined method 'characters' for nil:NilClass` error :/

Comment: Because there is no account instance variable. Also, your form is not right, it should be user, account ... instead of account, account